# Java change type of property for serialization

Tags: java, mysql, json, spring, spring-boot

I wanted to create a rest service for adding new users to the database.
So basically, the service would accept request like this:

{"login":"testUser","mail":"testUser@gmail.com","password":"123abc"}

And now the problem is: 
I have heard that we shouldn't store passwords as String, but as char arrays in Java, so that is what i did.

Here is my user class

```
package com.mailReminder.restservice.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String login;
    private String mail;

    private char[] password;

    private byte[] salt;

    public User(String login, String mail, char[] password) {
        this.login = login;
        this.mail = mail;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public User() {
        this.id = 0L;
        this.login = "";
        this.mail = "";
        this.password = null;
        this.salt = null;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getMail() {
        return mail;
    }

    public void setMail(String mail) {
        this.mail = mail;
    }

    public char[] getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(char[] password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public byte[] getSalt() {
        return salt;
    }

    public void setSalt(byte[] salt) {
        this.salt = salt;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", login='" + login + '\'' +
                ", mail='" + mail + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

In order to secure the password i use this encrypter:

```
package com.mailReminder.restservice.security;

import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;

public class PasswordSecurer{

    public static byte[] getSalt() {
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] salt = new byte[16];
        random.nextBytes(salt);

        return salt;
    }

    public static byte[] hashPassword(char[] password, byte[] salt) {
        int iterationCount = 65536;
        int keyLength = 640;

        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, iterationCount, keyLength);
        SecretKeyFactory factory = null;
        try {
            factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
            return factory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

So i need to convert char array to byte array, which works just fine. 
The problem is that, after the password is hashed, the char array is filled with something like this

[-108, -71, 126, -39, -6, 65, 50, 42, -51, 55, -88, -121, -103, 55, 109, 22, 12, -21, 33, 72, 122, -127, -31, 90, 49, 75, 90, -79, 83, -99, -50, -100, -66, 29, 45, -60, 8, 41, 1, 115, -65, -124, -5, -47, 71, -105, 28, -68, -128, 12, -111, -93, -27, -102, 51, -119, -99, 49, -23, -27, 96, -42, -128, 124, 61, -87, 17, -15, -46, -85, -16, -62, 106, -1, -79, 79, 53, 108, -56, -128]

And this is what now gets inserted to the database into varchar field, and it is parsed like this by jackson.

Here is the controller

```
package com.mailReminder.restservice.controller;

import com.mailReminder.restservice.model.User;
import com.mailReminder.restservice.repository.UserRepository;
import com.mailReminder.restservice.security.PasswordSecurer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.Arrays;

@RestController
public class UserController {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> register(@RequestBody User newUser) {
        byte[] salt = PasswordSecurer.getSalt();
        byte[] hashedPassword = PasswordSecurer.hashPassword(Arrays.toString(newUser.getPassword()).toCharArray(), salt);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(hashedPassword));
        if (hashedPassword == null)
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("");

        if (userRepository.findByLogin(newUser.getLogin()) != null)
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
                    .body("{\"errorCode\":400,\"errorMessage\":\"User already exists\"}");

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(hashedPassword));
        newUser.setPassword(Arrays.toString(hashedPassword).toCharArray());
        newUser.setSalt(salt);
        userRepository.save(newUser);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(newUser);
    }

    @GetMapping("/register")
    public @ResponseBody
    Iterable<User> getAllUsers() {

        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Before i decided to accept json as request, i used byte[] for passwords and this is how it looked like in database, and what i would like it to look like now.

bAz}+ø¶Eí|¿ºmÆ‡J¾½7HÏuBƒpl¾¤A4lypyí:Ç-eqÝ¸Ó¨Eó4¹ÝÍ6 žÊ©§_~9W¸Ô%œL—`Œ©cX§

But i can not change it to the byte[] in the User class, becouse then Jackson crashes with error:
  JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `byte[]` from String

So my question is: What i can do, to make my passwords look hashed again without changing char[] to String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the byte array and convert it to Base64:

```
byte[] bytes = {-108, -71, 126, -39, -6, 65, 50, 42, -51, 55, -88, -121, -103, 55, 109, 22, 12, -21, 33, 72, 122, -127, -31, 90, 49, 75, 90, -79, 83, -99, -50, -100, -66, 29, 45, -60, 8, 41, 1, 115, -65, -124, -5, -47, 71, -105, 28, -68, -128, 12, -111, -93, -27, -102, 51, -119, -99, 49, -23, -27, 96, -42, -128, 124, 61, -87, 17, -15, -46, -85, -16, -62, 106, -1, -79, 79, 53, 108, -56, -128};

String output = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);

System.out.println( "base64 is " + output );
```

Then you'll get:

```
base64 is lLl+2fpBMirNN6iHmTdtFgzrIUh6geFaMUtasVOdzpy+HS3ECCkBc7+E+9FHlxy8gAyRo+WaM4mdMenlYNaAfD2pEfHSq/DCav+xTzVsyIA=
```

Store this in your DB as a string and only compare against it.  Passwords should be one way - you'll now need a way to reset that password too in case of forgotten passwords.

Note that you'll also need to save the salt the same way so that you can validate the hash again later.